# Polynomial fixed point lemma, $p(p(\dots p(t))) = t \Rightarrow p(t)=t \vee p(p(t))=t$

Tags: polynomials

Does the following result: $$[ \ p(p(\dots p(t))) = t \ ] \Rightarrow [ \ p(t)=t \vee p(p(t))=t \ ]$$

(where $p$ is of course a polynomial) have a name? I need a (preferably elementary) proof of this. The LHS is the polynomial composed with itself $n \in \mathbb{N}$ times.

Comment: Visibly you got this from a video that you linked to in a comment at the answer by Did. Given that, you should have watched at least the relevant part of this video, and remark the assumptions $p\in\mathbf Z[X]$ and $t\in\mathbf Z$, which are essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $p(t)=\frac32t^2-\frac{19}2t+17$ and $t=2$.

Comment: $p(t)=4, \ p(p(t))=3, \ p(p(p(t)))=2=t$. So the statement is false. I've had this result noted on a bit of paper I've found and I managed to trace it back to the origin: http://youtu.be/lOVK-R7H6xc?t=4m3s (around the 4min mark if the link doesn't take you there automatically). I'm guessing I've misunderstood what he's saying, what should the correct phrasing be?

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:** What are the degrees of $p(p(t))$ and $p^{\circ n}(t)$ (the $n$-fold self-composition of $p$)? How do they relate to the degree of $p(t)$? <s>Can there be a constant term?</s>

---

NB. As Andres Caicedo remarks, there can be a constant term; I duly apologise for the oversight that gave rise to my misleading hint.

Comment: The degree of the $n$ fold composition is $n$ times the degree of the original. From the way you ask the question, I'm guess there can't be a constant term, but I don't see why.

Comment: By the way, yes, there can be a constant term. An example if $p(x)=-x+2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $t$ is supposed to be a concrete value rather than the indeterminate in which $p$ is a polynomial (this would be the most natural reading of the question as it is phrase) then the statement is false. For instance take $p(x)=x^2$ and $t$ a fifth root of unity like $\exp(2\pi\mathbf i/5)$, then $p(p(p(t)))=t^{16}=t$ but $p(t)=t^2\neq t$ and $p(p(t))=t^4\neq t$.

If $t$ is a indeterminate and $p(t)\in\mathbf C[t]$, then the statement is still false, taking $p(t)=\alpha t$ with $\alpha=\exp(2\pi\mathbf i/3)$ so that $p(t)\neq t$, $p(p(t))=\alpha^2t\neq t$ but $p(p(p(t)))=\alpha^3t=t$.

Comment: Presumably the OP is interested in real roots.

Comment: @Did: Nothing in the question mentions real numbers. In fact I surmise that this is about integer polynomials and integer roots, but that OP does not realise this. But guessing missing hypotheses is not my game.